# how to append jquery ajax (json) to table

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

i have a ajax call that retreives data and its success portion looks like this:

```
success: function(data) 
{               
$("table.table").append("<tr><td>" + data.member_id + "</td><td>" + data.comment + "</td></tr>");
}
```

the data variable is holding this data

```
[{"member_id":"2","comment":"kkk"},{"member_id":"1","comment":"this is admin 2"},{"member_id":"2","comment":"kkk"},{"member_id":"1","comment":"this is admin"}]
```

but the problem im getting is that the table td's contain undefined text. how do i fix this?

the hardcoded table looks like this:

```
<table class="table"></table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should loop through the array, can use `$.each` utility function:

```
$.each(json, function(i, data){
     $("table.table").append("<tr><td>" + data.member_id + "</td><td>" + data.comment + "</td></tr>");
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ADvCJ/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$.each(data, function(i,row){
  $("table.table").append("<tr><td>"+row['member_id']+"</td><td>"+row['comment']+"</td></tr>");
})
```