# Using jquery ajax need response from API to go into table HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

What I am trying to do is: user gets pick date range and clicks submit. Then the response from the API  goes into a table format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>main jQuery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <form>
        Enter a date after 2015-01-01:
        <input type="date" id="startDate" min="2015-01-01" max="2017-01-01"><br><br>
        Enter a date before 2017-01-01:
        <input type="date" id="endDate" min="2015-01-01" max="2017-01-01"><br><br>
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> type="date" only works on chrome</p>
    <table style="width:100%" id="table">
        <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Price</th> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    <div id="price"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>








$(document).on("click","#btn",function() {
    var startDate = $("#startDate").val();
    var endDate = $("#endDate").val();
    var Url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start=" + startDate + "&end=" + endDate;

    console.log(typeof(startDate));
    console.log(typeof(endDate));

    console.log(Url);

        $.ajax({
            url: Url,
            type:"GET",
            success: function(response) {
            // I do not know what to do in my success, cannot find a 
            // link to help me either. Maybe I googling incorrectly?
            },
            error:function(error){
                console.log('Error ${error}');
            }
        })
})
```

This is what my console shows. I cannot figure out what i need to put int he "success" portion of my ajax to successfully get my response. If someone can point me in the right direction I would truly appreciate it.

```
string
main.js:7 string
main.js:9 https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start=2016-12-06&end=2017-01-01
main.js:18 Error ${error}
```

Comment: This question has been asked here a number of times and maybe you might find one of the answers helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701963/append-jquery-ajax-json-to-table, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816537/how-to-append-jquery-ajax-json-to-table, and a bunch more here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ajax+json+to+table

Comment: success: function(response) {
            console.log(response); //show this response            }, Show the above success response. so can help you better.